# What are the hex codes for the blue, green, and orange used as the border, padding, and margin in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

The box model has a blue, green, and orange color associated with them, at least in chrome. I was wondering if anyone knew the hex color codes for these shades?

Comment: Screenshot then colour pick the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margin Color: `#f9cc9d`
Border Color: `#fddd9b`
Padding Color: `#c2cf8a`
Blue color: `#8bb5c0`

Comment: Awesome! Can I ask how you were able to figure these out?

Comment: Like I say, screen shot and colour pick surely :P